# Socket IO Emit to Backend when disconnect

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, socket.io, flask-socketio

I know this is a dumb questions, because how you can emit when it's disconnected. but I think that there is a solution.

My problem:

I have a chat app, using Socket IO, React FE and Flask BE. I want to somehow make that, when the Frontend is closed or disconnected, it sends something to the backend and i can remove the user from the chat and database. What would be the solution for this.

Thanks, any help appreciated

Comment: React uses `socket.close()` if you are using `const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('')`

Comment: I don§t have the require part, but I have the io.connect(). Thanks for help, I will try